# Select Everything After Greater Than in Python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a string

```
"Tyson Invitational 02/08/2013','#FFFFCC')""; ONMOUSEOUT=""kill()"" >6.54"
```

How would I use regex to select everything after the right-pointing bracket?  Aka how would I get the 6.54?

I've tried

```
\>(.*)
```

but I'm not sure it's working properly.  I use

```
m = re.search( '\>(.*)', row_out[5])
```

and get

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10b6105d0>
```

Not sure what the issue is.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you isolated the string, or are you trying to parse HTML? What you current have will work for the single sample input you have.

Comment: Use BeautifulSoup to parse XML / HTML

Comment: What exactly is the issue? You try to find something in a string, and the `search` function returns you a match object because it found what you where looking for. Maybe you just want `m.groups()[0]` or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> str="""Tyson Invitational 02/08/2013','#FFFFCC')""; ONMOUSEOUT=""kill()"" >6.54"""
>>> re.search('\>(.*)',str)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f0de9575558>
```

same as you got before.  However assign the search result to a variable and

```
>>> f=re.search('\>(.*)',str)
>>> f.groups()
('6.54',)
```